# Are surveys on-topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

Is it okay to ask for surveys here?

E.g.:

> I am looking for surveys indicating the percentage of Frenchmen who are in favor of allowing UberPOP in France.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes.** In fact survey data can be very structured and scientific. For example,

[Pew Research Center](http://www.pewresearch.org) is a

> conduct[s] public opinion polling, demographic research, content analysis and other data-driven social science research.

(Fancy ways of saying 'survey'.)

They offer [raw data](http://www.pewresearch.org/data/) that is used in their reports, and this kind of resource may be useful for answering OpenData questions about polling, surveys, etc.

Comment: Sounds good, I totally agree survey data is just as good as other kind of data, just subsampled.

Answer (score 3):

I would say **yes** because your question can easily be rephrased without asking for a survey, and you could get a survey as an answer:

*I am looking for data on the percentage of Frenchmen who are in favor of allowing UberPOP in France.*

[Added] Who knows what other data can pop up on the subject instead of just surveys. Maybe someone followed peoples' taxi behavior and found out how many switched to Uber ;-)

Comment: Good point about the possibility of other sources. Question asked: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/5878/1652